# How to use OpenCV from Xamarin (Android and iOS)?

Tags: c#, c++, ios, opencv, xamarin

I would like to create a mobile app using Xamarin for both iOS and Android, and I would like to call a few OpenCV functions (for example, contour detection and perspective transform).

I generally understand the process of calling C++ functions from C#, but I don't know how to do this from the [OpenCV binaries](https://opencv.org/releases.html) provided for iOS and Android. There's a [fork of OpenCvSharp](https://github.com/Kawaian/OpenCvSharp) that supports Xamarin.Android, but it doesn't support Xamarin.iOS.

I'm not looking to port the entire OpenCV library to Xamarin (yet). I'm just looking to call a very small subset of functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For iOS you should provide binding for Objective-C yourself. Here is an example of how to do, code is NOT mine.

https://github.com/trinnguyen/xamarin.ios-opencv

Here is an article describing the steps:
https://chamoda.com/how-to-use-opencv-with-xamarin-ios/

```
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface OpenCV
{

    [Export("version:")]
    NSString Version();

}

private OpenCV OpenCV = new OpenCV();

Console.WriteLine(OpenCV.Version());
```

Comment: I finally got around to doing this and after hours of trying it worked. However, an issue with this approach (which I've asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54729281/1383366)) is that my app ends up being >300 MB in size because opencv2.framework is that large.

Comment: I think you need to change the  [Export("version:")] to  [Export("version")], else it crashes coz it expects parameters to be passed.