# Create a single iOS static library file that includes the framework it depends on

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, xamarin, ios-frameworks

I have a large framework (in my case, [opencv2.framework](https://opencv.org/releases.html) and >300 MB) that my iOS static library depends on. Currently, projects that depend on my static library also need to link the framework. Is it possible to create a single static library that includes the framework in the same .a file? Additionally, can the size of the library be reduced to only contain what it needs so my app is not >300 MB?

If it matters, I'm actually going to use this static library in an iOS binding project, so that it can be consumed by a Xamarin.iOS app.

Comment: So you want to combine two `frameworks` into a `.a` file in iOS? And then binding that library to a Xamarin.iOS project?

Comment: Actually, only one is a framework (OpenCV), and the other is my own static library that depends on OpenCV. I would like to bundle these into a single .a file (with minimal size) and use that in a Xamarin.iOS project.