# How to use openCV in Xamarin?

Tags: opencv, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, emgucv

I am creating a Xamarin project to detect some objects in images .
I want to use openCV library , but I can't wrap it to the xamarin .

I wrapped it to an windows form application but I can not wrap it to Xamarin (I got errors in compatibility)
I have tried to install EMGU.cv but I got error : unable to find version 3.4.3 
also I can't update it .

I also tried to wrap the openCV to xamarin by downloading the openCV from here https://opencv.org/releases/
but I didn't find the the .jar file to add it the my project .

so how can I use openCV in xamarin please ?

also is object detection applicable with openCV or not ?

Comment: This question seems like to be duplicate .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260093/how-to-use-opencv-from-xamarin-android-and-ios

Answer (score 1):

Luckily there is some work done by people before [you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260093/how-to-use-opencv-from-xamarin-android-and-ios). You can already use the wrapper that's created for Android, but for iOS you'll have to try to create the wrapper yourself

Edit from 2022: For Android you can also take a look at [this GitHub sample](https://github.com/VieXam/Xamarin.Android.OpenCV), amongst many others